# Pointwise Convergence In Integral

Tags: integration, limits, analysis, pointwise-convergence

This question's my profesors. I know $x^n$ is a pointwise convergent sequence. But I don't know how can I show that this limit. Can you show me solution of this question.

$f:[0, 1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous function.

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\int_0^{1}x^nf(x) \, dx$$

Find the limit.

Comment: Hint: $f$ is bounded.

Comment: Yes, thank you. @StubbornAtom

Answer (score 3):

Since $f$ is continuous, it is bounded on $[0,1]$, say by $M >0$. Then,

$$\left\lvert \int_0^1 x^n f(x) \,dx \right\rvert \leq \int_0^1 x^n |f(x)| \,dx \leq M \int_0^1 x^n \,dx = \frac{M}{n+1} \to 0$$

as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you but how did 1/n+1 happen?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus

Comment: @bosanac $\int x^n=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$

Comment: Sorry sorry... I confused... Thank you so much.